# parameter '@xxx' has already been declared

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database-connection

Here i am trying to update the details in my mysql database, but its not updating the details but showing done. After that if i try to update the same thing its is showing Parameter '@Unique ID' has already been declared.

Below here is my update Button section of the application i am building.

```cs
private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server = " + server + ";" + "user Id = " + username + ";" + "password  = " + password + ";" + "database = " + database;
    
    
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand();
        sqlConn.Open();
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "Update `monthly_expense`.`exp_mast` set `Unique ID`= '@Unique ID', `First Name`=  '@First Name',`Last Name`= '@Last Name',`Address`= '@Address',`Contact Number`= '@Contact Number',`Alternate Contact Number`= '@Alt Number',`Gender`= '@gen' Where(`Unique ID`= '@Unique ID')";
        if (rb_male.Checked == true)
        {
            gen = "Male";
        }
        else
        {
            gen = "Female";
        }
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unique ID", txt_id.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First Name", txt_fstn.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last Name", txt_lstn.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txt_loc.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact Number", txt_cont.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alt Number", txt_altcont.Text);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gen", gen);

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: `MySqlCommand sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand();` declares `sqlcmd` (all lowercase) whereas everything else in the method uses `sqlCmd` (uppercase C). This leads me to think that you have declared `sqlCmd` elsewhere (somewhere that persists between calls to this section of code - perhaps as a field variable in the class?) and are therefore adding the parameters to it over and over and over again. Anyway, VTC as typo.

Comment: `MySqlCommand sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand();` has been declared globally also

Comment: Yes, but the `sqlcmd` in `btn_Update_Click` takes precedence over the "global" `sqlcmd`.

Comment: In case my previous comment was unclear: C# is case sensitive, so `sqlcmd` and `sqlCmd` in the code of `btn_Update_Click` don't refer to the same variable.

Comment: Your code looks correct and execution also does not throw any error... so it must be the data issue... you might want to verify the values entered in the `text_id` is correct... also you might want to run the same query in workbench and see if it updates the value in the table. All other update/insert queries in the application works fine?

Comment: Running the same query in workbench is working fine and the data is updated too. @Chetan

Comment: sorry... this comment was for your other question.

Comment: Its ok not a problem @Chetan