# Database data Not updating

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, database-connection

I am trying to update my details in Database.
Below here is the code I have written.

The Problem I am facing is, the details is not updating in the database instead of the program running successfully.

What could be the problem?

```
private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server = " + server + ";" + "user Id = " + username + ";" + "password  = " + password + ";" + "database = " + database;
        sqlConn.Open();

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand sqlCmd=new MySqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "Update `monthly_expense`.`exp_mast` set `Unique ID`= '@Unique ID', `First Name`=  '@First Name',`Last Name`= '@Last Name',`Address`= '@Address',`Contact Number`= '@Contact Number',`Alternate Contact Number`= '@Alt Number',`Gender`= '@gen' Where(`Unique ID`= '@Unique ID')";
            if (rb_male.Checked == true)
            {
                gen = "Male";
            }
            else
            {
                gen = "Female";
            }
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unique ID", txt_id.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First Name", txt_fstn.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last Name", txt_lstn.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txt_loc.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact Number", txt_cont.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alt Number", txt_altcont.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gen", gen);

            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

            txt_fstn.Clear();
            txt_lstn.Clear();
            txt_loc.Clear();
            txt_cont.Clear();
            txt_altcont.Clear();
            if (rb_male.Checked)
            {
                rb_male.Checked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                rb_Female.Checked = false;
            }
            txt_id.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking at the right database? how have you proven its not updating?

Comment: What is the different to this question you already asked? [parameter '@xxx' has already been declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69097731/parameter-xxx-has-already-been-declared)

Comment: Yes I am checking the right database @TheGeneral

Comment: In the previous question It wasn't showing done where as now its showing done but the cells are not updated @jason.kaisersmith

Comment: Are you checking in the database to see if the table is updated? Are you checking via running SELECT statement in workbench?

Comment: Doing both @Chetan

Comment: Hi, your parameter should not have space. `@UniqueID` instead of `@Unique ID`. And in your query, don't put quotes for `'@Unique ID'`. For example: `UPDATE ... SET [Unique ID]= @UniqueID ...`. The command will append the parameter value with quote such as set `[Unique ID]= '123'`. Note: I use square bracket to replace '`' as the syntax breaks in comment.

Comment: Your code looks correct and execution also does not throw any error... so it must be the data issue... you might want to verify the values entered in the text_id is correct... also you might want to run the same query in workbench and see if it updates the value in the table. All other update/insert queries in the application works fine?

Comment: yes Insert is working fine, and running the same query in the workbench is updating the data in the table properly. The problem occurring only in the application @Chetan

Comment: @YongShun It will actually **NOT** update the sql statement to use quotes. The whole point of parameters is the statement is _never udpated_, but rather the parameter values are kept as variables, just like if you had defined a stored procedure. In this way, any possible of injection is completely prevented because the data and the sql command never intermingle.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the parameter names in quotes in the SQL, and don't use spaces. This is wrong:

```
set `Unique ID`= '@Unique ID'
```

It makes it look like setting the `Unique ID` field to the string value `@Unique ID`. You want this instead:

```
set `Unique ID`= @UniqueID
```

Of course, also update the `AddWithValue()` lines appropriately for the new parameter names.

Also, the `sqlConn.Close()` call should be in the `finally` block.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "Update `monthly_expense`.`exp_mast` set `Unique_ID`= @Unique_ID, `First_Name`=  @First_Name,`Last_Name`= @Last_Name,`Address`= @Address,`Contact_Number`= @Contact_Number,`Alternate_Contact_Number`= @Alt_Number,`Gender`= @gen Where(`Unique_ID`= @Unique_ID);COMMIT;";
```

check fields name .. there is no space in names or parameters name

expand answer:

this my real code similar to yours and work good :

```
        private void linkSaveProfile_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        using var conn = new MySqlConnection(DbConnectionString);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            var sql = "UPDATE users_profile SET " +
                      "first_name = @pfirst_name," +
                      "mid_name = @pmid_name," +
                      "last_name = @plast_name," +
                      "gender = @pgender," +
                      "education = @peducation," +
                      "country = @pcountry," +
                      "city = @pcity," +
                      "state = @pstate," +
                      "country_key = @pcountry_key," +
                      "mobile = @pmobile," +
                      "birth_year = @pbirth_year," +
                      "about = @pabout," +
                      "description = @pdescription," +
                      "is_public_description = @pis_public_description," +
                      "website = @pwebsite," +
                      "facebook = @pfacebook," +
                      "linkedin = @plinkedin," +
                      "skype = @pskype," +
                      "twitter = @ptwitter," +
                      "channel_name = @pchannel_name," +
                      "channel_lang = @pchannel_lang," +
                      "exper_year = @pexper_year," +
                      "exper_forex = @pexper_forex," +
                      "exper_stocks = @pexper_stocks," +
                      "exper_cfd = @pexper_cfd " +
                      "WHERE user_id = @puser_id;COMMIT; ";

            var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@puser_id", UserId);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pfirst_name", textFirstName.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pmid_name", textMidName.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plast_name", textLastName.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pgender", radioMale.Checked ? "male" : "female");
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@peducation", textEducation.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcountry", comboCountry.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcity", textCity.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pstate", textState.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcountry_key", textCountryKey.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pmobile", textMobile.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pbirth_year", textBirthYear.Value);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pabout", textAbout.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdescription", textDescription.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pis_public_description", checkPublicDescription.Checked);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwebsite", textWebsite.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pfacebook", textFacebook.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plinkedin", textLinkedin.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pskype", textSkype.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ptwitter", textTwitter.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pchannel_name", textChannelName.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pchannel_lang", textChannelLang.Text);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pexper_year", textExperianceYear.Value);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pexper_forex", checkForex.Checked);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pexper_stocks", checkStocks.Checked);
            _ = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pexper_cfd", checkCFD.Checked);


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), @"Error");
        }

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
```

may be some DB engines allowed space .. I was wrong in this point.

I use COMMIT;  in the end of query to make sure my updating is done .
whatever server setting .

Comment: Hey waddah, would be nice if you could add more information about why the spacing is required in this case for it to work.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.